# setting an array element with a sequence error python sklearn svm

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn, svm

I have the following code

```
import pandas
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import preprocessing
import ast
import array
import numpy as np
'''
list = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    fakeList = [[i - 1, i, i + 1], 1]
    list.append(fakeList)
list = pandas.DataFrame(list)
list.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
'''

data = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')
data = data.head(11)
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(columns=list(data.columns.values))
# print(data)
# print(len(data.index))
#le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
for i in range(0, len(data.index)):
    str = data.loc[i, '0']
    #print (i)
    #print (str)
    mlist = np.empty(3)
    #print(len(mlist))
    # list=[]
    mlist[0] = float(ast.literal_eval(str)[0])
    mlist[1] = float(ast.literal_eval(str)[1])
    mlist[2] = float(ast.literal_eval(str)[2])
    # print(len(list))
   # list=le.fit(list)
    #print (list[0])
    data.set_value(i, '0', mlist)
#print(data)
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    newRow = np.asarray(row)
    df2.loc[index]=newRow
print (df2)
training_labels = df2['1'].values
training_features = df2.drop('1', axis=1).values
# training_features=np.asarray(training_features)
# training_labels=np.asarray(training_labels)
model = svm.SVC()
model.fit(training_features, training_labels)
```

and my csv file is in the following format

```
0   1
[-1, 0, 1]  1
[0, 1, 2]   1
[1, 2, 3]   1
[2, 3, 4]   1
[3, 4, 5]   1
[4, 5, 6]   1
[5, 6, 7]   1
[6, 7, 8]   1
[7, 8, 9]   1
[8, 9, 10]  1
```

I keep getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 46, in <module>
    model.fit(training_features, training_labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 151, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64, order='C', accept_sparse='csr')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 521, in check_X_y
    ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 382, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I researched quite a bit, it seems this error is caused when the arrays are of not of the same size while calling model.fit(X,y).
But my arrays are as far as I can tell of the same size. Please tell me what it the mistake here.
Thank you

Update: The problem is in DataFrame column 2, where there is an array. If I replace the array with single integer values, the model loads fine. Is there any way to pass multidimensional value to svm classifier? I know it is possible to break the values into seperate columns, but the project I am doing right now has more than 500 value in an array. So it would be difficult to break them up in single cells.

Comment: after the line `data = pandas.read_csv('test.csv')` , print data and see if the CSV data has loaded properly. I suspect that the `read_csv()` determines the separator incorrectly.  Add a [separator directives](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and define the separator, in your case 'space'. See if that might resolve the problem.

Comment: Sorry I copied the csv data from excel, so the separator is 'comma'. The problem is in the column 2, where I try to pass an array to model.fit. If I put a single integer there the model works fine

Comment: So the problem is obvious. Your code splits the CSV when it sees a comma. You will either have to escape it or use  different separator. Tab is my suggestion. Or perhaps  you may have to write a custom function to read the CSV file. I'll add some pseudo code as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, But I can get the array elements, I can even print them, add them or do any operations on them. The issue is when I try to pass them as an array to svm model. I don't think separator is an issue. Thank you for the reply though.